# SendGrid: Sending an email to multiple recipients without other emails being shown on the "to" field

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to send an email to multiple recipients.

I used [personalizations](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html), but everyone's emails appears on the "to" field, which violates their privacy.

I don't want to use BCC as this often goes straight to junk (e.g. http://www.standss.com/blog/index.php/why-you-should-avoid-using-bcc-for-emails/).

Therefore my question is, how can I send an email to multiple recipients without everyones emails appearing on the "to" field.

My only alternative I can see is send a separate request to the API for each and every email using a loop which is very resource intensive and time consuming when I have a lot of emails to send!

Comment: Can't you write a script that loops around all the recipients and calls the API for each one?

Comment: Yes but that seems quite resource intensive if say I'm going through 30,000 emails

Comment: I don't know if you still need this, but here's the official documentation, https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#send-multiple-emails-to-multiple-recipients

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using SendGrid's Personalizations with multiple recipient groups, you need to define [multiple 1st-level objects within the Personalization array](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html#-Sending-Two-Different-Emails-to-Two-Different-Groups-of-Recipients).

So instead of:

```
{"personalizations": [
{"to": [
    {"email": "recipient1@example.com"},
    {"email": "recipient2@example.com"}
]}]}
```

which will all be a common `To:` array that can see each other,

You want:

```
{"personalizations": [
{"to": [{"email": "recipient1@example.com"}]},
{"to": [{"email": "recipient2@example.com"}]}
]}
```

Within each personalization level, you can customize the content, subject, substitution tags, pretty much everything.

So you can build out the full personalization, and iterate through those 1000 times. Once you have your 1000 recipients, bundle them into a single API call, then send that.

Comment: Interesting. How can I do this use the PHP SDK

Comment: per the ['kitchen sink'](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L54) example, you'll just want to make a new instance of the Personalization object, populate it, then add it to the mail object.

Comment: you can do this ith PHP SDK by creating multiple Personalization objects. Example in link https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L22

Comment: For those using node client (`"@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0"`, currently), you can set the `isMultiple` parameter in the `send()` call, while using the regular `to` array: `await client.send(message, isMultiple);` with `message.to = [email1, email2]` and `isMultiple = true`.

Answer (score 3):

To build on @jacobmovingfwd, here's an example in Python that sends the same email to multiple recipients with individualized "to" fields. I've tested the code, and it works for me.

```
# Given a list of email addresses that are strings
sublist = [...]    

mail = Mail()

for to_email in sublist:
    # Create new instance for each email
    personalization = Personalization()
    # Add email addresses to personalization instance
    personalization.add_to(Email(to_email))
    # Add personalization instance to Mail object
    mail.add_personalization(personalization)

# Add data that is common to all personalizations
mail.from_email = Email(from_email)
mail.subject = subject
mail.add_content(Content('text/plain', message_txt))
mail.add_content(Content('text/html', message_html))

# Send
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a C# version that clones Personalization for each recipient to be mailed separately, but still with a single SendGrid API call:

```
    public static void SendEachReceipient(SendGridMessage msg, IEnumerable<string> recipients)
    {
        if (msg == null || recipients == null || !recipients.Any())
            return;

        if (msg.Personalizations == null) //can easily be null if no substitutions have not been added
            msg.Personalizations = new List<Personalization>();

        var substitutionsCopy = msg.Personalizations.FirstOrDefault()?.Substitutions; //all substitutions (if any) are always all contained in the first personalization
        msg.Personalizations.Clear(); //we will start fresh - one personalization per each receipient to keep emails private from each other

        foreach (var email in recipients.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Distinct())
        {
            var personalization = new Personalization();
            personalization.Substitutions = substitutionsCopy;
            personalization.Tos = new List<EmailAddress>() { new EmailAddress(email) };
            msg.Personalizations.Add(personalization);
        }

        var result = new SendGridClient("api-key").SendEmailAsync(msg).Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to prepare the below type of JSON

```
{
"personalizations": [
    {
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "mail here",
                "name": "name here"
            }
        ],
        "subject": "subject for individual person"
    },
    {
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "mail here",
                "name": "name here"
            }
        ],
        "subject": "if you want to send a dynamic subject then write here",
    }
],
"from": {
    "email": "mail here",
    "name": "name here"
},
"reply_to": {
    "email": "mail here",
    "name": "name here"
},
"subject": "subject here",
"content": [
    {
        "type": "text/html",
        "value": "<p>Hello from Twilio first!</p>"
    }
],
"attachments": [
    {
        "content": "PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbmc9ImVuIj4KCiAgICA8aGVhZD4KICAgICAgICA8bWV0YSBjaGFyc2V0PSJVVEYtOCI+CiAgICAgICAgPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iWC1VQS1Db21wYXRpYmxlIiBjb250ZW50PSJJRT1lZGdlIj4KICAgICAgICA8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJ2aWV3cG9ydCIgY29udGVudD0id2lkdGg9ZGV2aWNlLXdpZHRoLCBpbml0aWFsLXNjYWxlPTEuMCI+CiAgICAgICAgPHRpdGxlPkRvY3VtZW50PC90aXRsZT4KICAgIDwvaGVhZD4KCiAgICA8Ym9keT4KCiAgICA8L2JvZHk+Cgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==",
        "filename": "index.html",
        "type": "text/html",
        "disposition": "attachment"
    }
] 
}
```